# How to make Angular understand what element I'm referring to while dynamically loading element in the template?

Tags: angular, angular-material, runtime, ngfor, mat-select

I had to make a component that dynamically creates mat-selects when clicking a add button.
The point is that the user can select a value from each mat-select and then everything gets sent to the parent component with an output.

This is the logic that I used

The component starts with a array of strings with only one element:

```
export class DynamicMatSelectComponent {
    matSelects: string[] = [""];
}
```

In the template I have this:

```
<div *ngFor="let matSelect of matSelects; let i = index">
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="matSelects[i]" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange(i, $event)"
        // mat options
    </mat-select>
</div>
```

I then have a button that when clicked simply adds a empty string to the `matSelects` array so that the ngFor makes more of mat-select.

The problem is that when I create multiple mat-selects and I choose a option for, let's say, the first one, the second one also gets updated with the same value as the first one.

I really don't know how to get around this because I haven't found a clear way to make sure that I'm targeting only a specific mat-select.
I believe the problem has something to do with the fact that I'm making stuff up at runtime and maybe I'm not following the correct methodology.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer was easier than I thought.
Basically instead of having a array of string, I made an array of objects like this: `matSelects: any[] = [{ value: "" }];` and each time I click the add button I do this: `this.matSelects.push({ value: "" });`.
Now it looks like it always targets the right mat-select, maybe it has something to do with the reference of objects